# Android WIFI Hotspot

Tags: wifi-hotspot, mac-address

Does anyone know where android save the details (Mac, etc.) of devices that connected **to my phone** ?! (When my device is used as a  mobile hotsop)

Answer (score -2):

On my device it's `/data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml`
You will need root to access it.

Comment: Hello. In my OnePlus 6 running Android 10, in that file all I get to see are the MAC entries of the WiFi/hotspot devices my device has ever connected to. On the other hand, OP is asking the details of the devices connected to his own Android hotspot. Can you mention whether you are able to get this information in that file too, and in which Android version and device?